# Matrix dimensions error when using norm()

Tags: matlab, matrix, dimensions, equation-solving, linear-equation

I'm trying to use MATLAB to run Richardson's iteration for computing the solution of a linear system, Ax=b. I wrote a function to do this, but got an error when I tried to run it. The following is my function where `x0` is the initial iterate, `L` is the maximum number of iterations, `A` is a nonsingular nxn matrix, `b` is a `n`-length vector, `a` is in place of the alpha parameter required for the algorithm, `tol` is the desired level of precision, `x` is a `n`-length vector, and `k` is the actual number of iterations:

```
function [x,k]=Richardson(x0,L,A,b,a,tol)
n = size(b);
x1 = x0 + a*(b-A*x0);
Norm = norm(x1-x0)/sqrt(n);
k = 1;
x0 = x1;
while (Norm > tol) && (k < L)
    x1 = x0 + a*(b-A*x0);
    Norm = norm(x1-x0)/sqrt(n);
    k = k + 1;
    x0 = x1;
end
x = x1;
```

I tried to run this function using the following:

```
x0=[0;0;0];
L = 10;
A=[1,0,0;0,2,0;0,0,4];
b=[1;1;1];
a=-1;
tol=10.^(-5);

a1=Richardson(x0,L,A,b,a,tol)
```

This was the error I got:

```
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in Richardson (line 4)
Norm = norm(x1-x0)/sqrt(n);

Error in HW8 (line 11)
a1=Richardson(x0,L,A,b,a,tol)
```

I don't see how this is the case, because `x0` and `x1` are both `n`-length vectors. Am I implementing this incorrectly?

Comment: I'd highly recommend learning [MATLAB's debugger](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) so you can see if your variables have the dimensions you think they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = size(b);
```

Results in a 2 values vector (3,1 in your case). So you can't divide a single value by 2 values. Change to 
`n = size(b,1)` or `n=size(b,2)` to get what you need (rows or columns).